# dropdown and textarea binding with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very simple scenario and I wanted to use AngularJS for that. I am not able to get this one right.

I am retrieving data from database and directly writing it into the view inside dropdown. From their based on which item is selected, I want to populate the value into textbook.

So my code for it is as follows:

```
<select>
  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">dropdown</option>
  @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in ViewBag.Template.Rows)
  {
    <option value="@row[1].ToString()">@row[0].ToString()</option>
  }
</select>
<textarea></textarea>
```

I am trying to achieve following:

whatever option user select, the corresponding value for the item be populated into text area.

Please suggest how can I achieve using AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive for that, the same for both select and textarea:

```
<select ng-model="selectModel">
  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">dropdown</option>
  @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in ViewBag.Template.Rows)
  {
    <option value="@row[1].ToString()">@row[0].ToString()</option>
  }
</select>
<textarea ng-model="selectModel"></textarea>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/XOs6wUyqdr3ZlFtBq3RB?p=preview